# What do the numbers on a zener diode signify

Tags: diodes, terminology, symbol

I have a zener diode obtained by reverse engineering, there is an icon of what is surely the mathematical model, and there are two numbers 41 and underneath 48, what do these signify?

Comment: That's not what [reverse engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering) means.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you have a [1N4148](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1N4148) rectifier, and not in fact a zener diode. The icon is likely the manufacturer's logo.

Comment: looks exactly like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=zener+diode&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=hHuTVIKOGYKZNuGGgIgG&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=667#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=MSxHeLo6sep8hM%253A%3BQq4Z9n5tZPhAzM%3Bhttps%253A%252F%252Felectrosome.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2012%252F12%252FZener-Diode.jpg%3Bhttps%253A%252F%252Felectrosome.com%252Fzener-diode-voltage-regulator%252F%3B640%3B640)

Comment: That's the [Fairchild Semi logo](https://www.google.ca/search?q=fairchild&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=8XuTVLXZJIqyggTMj4SYAw&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1011&bih=618#tbm=isch&q=fairchild+logo&revid=1796932696&facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=taetRiFyhDK8oM%253A%3BalGQr8CaqcOSpM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fimg2.wikia.nocookie.net%252F__cb20070327080501%252Fhowto%252Fen%252Fimages%252F4%252F47%252FIc_manuf_logo--Fairchild_Semi-1.gif%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fhow-to.wikia.com%252Fwiki%252FFile%253AIc_manuf_logo--Fairchild_Semi-1.gif%3B108%3B78).

Comment: You cant blame me for thinking [otherwise](https://www.google.com/search?q=zener+diode+graph&es_sm=93&biw=1366&bih=667&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=QnyTVL7DG9HkgwS9qYHADw&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=Zfoa9mBGg_advM%253A%3BfutxDIAlAHKOsM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.electronics-tutorials.ws%252Fdiode%252Fdiode11.gif%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.electronics-tutorials.ws%252Fdiode%252Fdiode_7.html%3B507%3B387) thank you though

Answer (score 1):

There is a 95%  chance that what Ignacio says is correct and that you have a 1N4148 **NON**-zener diode.

Showing a page of pictures of zener diode curves has no obvious correlation with your described problem.

Looking at [this page of images](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=zener+diode+graph&es_sm=93&biw=1366&bih=667&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=QnyTVL7DG9HkgwS9qYHADw&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&gws_rd=cr#tbm=isch&q=1n4148&imgdii=_) which are of 1N4148 (NON zener) diodes is liable to be more relevant.

Your "looks exactly like this" link MAY produce different results for different people dueto 'how the system works'.

A photo of what you wish to reverse engineer would be most useful.